# Create-React-App v2 with Node-SASS and CSS Modules works locally but crashes in Heroku

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, react-css-modules

I'm using Create-React-App v2 and have installed `node-sass`. I also wish to use CSS Modules so I've changed the extensions and imports to `.module.scss`.

Note: I've imported the variables (_color.scss, _type.scss) into each component's stylesheet but it is not working so I've manually imported each needed variable to each component's stylesheet for now.

So now the app works locally but crashes in Heroku. `Heroku logs` states `build failed` and give 3 build output links for troubleshooting assistance. Here are the following build outputs.

1ST BUILD OUTPUT

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 10.x...
       Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.4.1

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 36784 packages in 17.665s
       found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > webportfolio@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_946ff21a3c8a665eda74215ba467f646
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/App.js
       Cannot find file './Components/Portfolio/Portfolio' in './src'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webportfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webportfolio@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.EQOTa/_logs/2019-03-11T23_54_27_075Z-debug.log
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
       Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
       during Node.js builds.
       Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

2ND BUILD OUTPUT

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 10.x...
       Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.4.1

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 36784 packages in 17.814s
       found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > webportfolio@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_85b1987ab543478c5aee6f4728e8b330
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/App.js
       Cannot find file './Components/Portfolio/Portfolio' in './src'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webportfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webportfolio@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.htJgH/_logs/2019-03-12T00_00_58_185Z-debug.log
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
       Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
       during Node.js builds.
       Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

3RD BUILD OUTPUT

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.5.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 10.5.0...
       Downloading and installing node 10.5.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.1.0

-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > node-sass@4.11.0 install /tmp/build_17cf925c197f17907d43d6369284d804/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js

       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build_17cf925c197f17907d43d6369284d804/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.Dfkzs/node-sass/4.11.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node

       > node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall /tmp/build_17cf925c197f17907d43d6369284d804/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js

       Binary found at /tmp/build_17cf925c197f17907d43d6369284d804/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine
       added 1883 packages from 750 contributors and audited 36784 packages in 39.346s
       found 63 low severity vulnerabilities
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > webportfolio@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_17cf925c197f17907d43d6369284d804
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/App.js
       Cannot find file './Components/Portfolio/Portfolio' in './src'.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webportfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webportfolio@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Dfkzs/_logs/2019-03-12T01_08_21_381Z-debug.log
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
       Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
       during Node.js builds.
       Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Solutions I've attempted:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#check-your-gitignore
- uninstalling the global instance of npm, then reinstalled the latest recommended-for-most users version
- npm rebuild node-sass

I've been stuck for awhile and would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Package installed

```
• Node.js v10.15.3 to /usr/local/bin/node
• npm v6.4.1 to /usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: Here's your problem: `Cannot find file './Components/Portfolio/Portfolio' in './src'.` Change this line: https://github.com/KenAustria/WebPortfolio/blob/master/src/App.js#L2 to `import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio/Portfolio';`.

Comment: @MattCarlotta I'm sorry, lowercasing the 'c' in Components, would fail as the folder is titled 'Components'? I tried it and it failed to compile as expected.

Comment: What was the failure message? According to your github repo, it's `components`, not `Components`. See: https://github.com/KenAustria/WebPortfolio/tree/master/src/components

Comment: @MattCarlotta Yes apologies, you are right. On my editor, it's with a `C` and not `c`. When I change it to `c` it gives me this error. `Failed to compile: Cannot find file: 'Portfolio.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './src/components/Portfolio/Components'.`

Comment: You have quite a few errors that need to be resolved. Forked your repo, should have a fixed version soon.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thanks so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... this project needs a lot of stylesheet reworking.

All of your **component level** `.scss` files should be **within the same folder** as the `component` that requires it. Any **partial files** should be **imported within the component-level scss** that needs them. Some of your stylesheets are doing it, but some aren't. Also, for whatever reason, you're importing partials within a `css` stylesheet and importing partials within `scss` stylesheets. Just stick to `scss` stylesheets!

To summarize:

- Any stylesheet that needs to be used by a `component` should be within the
  same folder as the `component`.
- Any stylesheet that needs to be used by many components, should be a partial file that is imported into a component-level stylesheet.

Right now you have partials, like `_app_portfolio.scss` files under `Sass` and component level `Portfolio.module.scss` stylesheets which are separately being required for `Portfolio.js`. This is an antipattern. Partials should be **reusebale stylesheets** that will imported into multiple **component level stylesheets** for re-usage.

For example, you should structure your app like so: (**for simplicity, your main directory folders should be lowercase**):

```
├── src
|   ├── components
|   |   └── Portfolio
|   |       ├── Portfolio.js
|   |       └── Portfolio.scss  (non-partial file, this component-level stylesheet contains all of styles required for Portfolio.js)
|   |   
|   ├── images
|   ├── styles
|   |   ├── base
|   |   |   └── _base.scss (partial file, include any DOM-level styles like "a" or "p", or "div", "body", "html" ... etc.)
|   |   |
|   |   ├── exts
|   |   |   └── _extensions.scss (partial file, include any extended styles like ".clear fix", which is a classname that'll contain repetitive style patterns)
|   |   |
|   |   ├── globals
|   |   |   └── globals.scss (non-partial file, include any GLOBAL stylesheets, like "normalize.css", this stylesheet will be directly imported into ./src/index.js like so: import "./styles/globals/globals.scss";)
|   |   |
|   |   ├── mixins
|   |   |   └── _mixins.scss (partial file, define your mixins that'll be shared with component-level scss)
|   |   |
|   |   ├── vars
|   |   |   └── _vars.scss (partial file, define your variables that'll be shared with component-level scss)
|   |   |
|   |   └── index.scss (OPTIONAL non-partial file that imports all of the partial files above, then this file can be imported into a component-level stylesheet. Instead of writing 4 imports for base, exts, mixins and vars, you'll just do: @import '../path/to/styles/index.scss'; now you have included all 4 partials within 1 import)
|   |
|   └── index.js
```

---

How to implement the above...

**components/Portfolio/Portfolio.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Profile from "../Profile/Profile";
import { portfolioContainer } from "./Portfolio.scss"; // import the className, if there are many classes, then just import them as "styles" from './stylesheet.scss'; then use: "styles.portfolioContainer", "styles.example", "styles.example2" ...etc

const Portfolio = () => {
  return (
    <div className={portfolioContainer}>
      <Profile />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;
```

**components/Portfolio/Portfolio.scss**

```
@import '../../styles/vars/vars.scss'; // partial file import, now we can use $variables
@import '../../styles/mixins/mixins.scss'; // partial file import, now we can use @include mixinname();
@import '../../styles/exts/extensions.scss'; // partial file import, now we can use @extend .classname;

.portfolioContainer {
  @include grid-template-columns(1);
  color: $brightgreen;
  background: url('../../images/example.png'); // include your image imports within the component-level stylesheet -- if you import it in a partial file, then import that partial within a stylesheet, then you'll run into some pathing issues. The path defined will be relative to the partial and won't be an absolute path to the image when imported within the component-level stylesheet.
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;

  &::after {
    @extend .clear-fix;
  }
}
```

Take a look at this [Sass Basics Guide](https://sass-lang.com/guide).

If you're having a hard time understanding, please see my [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit), which includes notes within [styles/index.scss](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/styles/index.scss#L1-L48) and [styles/globals/globals.scss](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/styles/globals/globals.scss#L1-L32) and how to utilize partials in [components/Home/Home.scss](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/components/Home/Home.scss) and be imported into [components/Home/Home.js](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/components/Home/Home.js#L3) and how to utilize globals in [src/index.js](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/index.js#L4).

Since you're using the `create-react-app`, you may need a sass-compiler to compile the `.scss` files to one or many `.css` files. Unfortunately, I don't use the CRA, so you'll have to dive into the docs to find out how.

Comment: I can't appreciate you enough! I'm going to implement what you've advised and will get back with results.

Comment: No problem! If you get stuck, feel free to ask.

Comment: It works! I'm appreciative of the effort you took in helping me understand my mistakes. I'd like to buy you coffee (electronic donation). Kindly let me know how to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it all figured out! Congrats! If you'd like to buy me a coffee, you can find a link my profile description. Happy coding.